# Firebase dynamic link click counts not increasing and more

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

As the title says, in the firebase dashboard, a link click count not increasing and stays at 0. There's something more. The dynamic links are missing `isi` parameter in the long URL which is required to open the app's App Store page. (Yeah I've already added team/app id and selected the responsible app in a link generation process)

Am I the only one here?

Edit: Yes, I'm sure that the link is clicked.

Comment: Did you found soulution for this? I am facing same issue.

Comment: @viveks sorry I don't remember xD.